# How to make Firefox handle Unix-style paths on Windows

Tags: windows, firefox, python, path, clipboard

I added an option to the context menu in Windows 10 to allow me to copy the paths of (local) files or folders to my clipboard. E.g. if I right-click on C:/users/simon/example.pdf, that path gets copied to the clipboard.

I did this because I very regularly have to copy paths of files, often either to a Python notebook in Jupyter / Python files in PyCharm, to the url bar in Firefox, or to windows explorer.

However, I run into a fundamental error: should the path use /, \\, or \ as a separator?

- In Python only \\ and / work
- In windows explorer only / and \ work
- In Firefox \\ and \ get converted to a path starting with "file:///", but "/" does not and results in a google search instead.

Is there a way to make Firefox automatically add "file:///" to paths using / as separator? Or alternatively, is there another way to make all three use cases handle the same path correctly? Or to get the right style for the right application from the clipboard?

Comment: I just pasted `C:\Temp\Test.txt` in the Firefox address bar, it was converted by Firefox to `file:///C:/Temp/test.txt` and opened just fine. If the path is quoted (`"C:\Temp\Test.txt"`), Firefox treats it as a search string.

Comment: A workaround would be to create a shortcut to Firefox in `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo`. This will show up in Explorer's context menu (under *Send To*)

Comment: @Berend Sorry, I mixed up the forward and backward slashes. I've edited my question with the correct ones

Comment: You say "In Python only \\ and / work", but that is incorrect. Prefix a string literal with `r` to make it a raw string, so it doesn't escape sequences like `\n`. For example, this works fine in Python: `r"C:\users\simon\example.pdf"`

Comment: @GordonAitchJay okay, fair, yes that's an option, but that's still manually working around the problem. I'm trying to automate the process in such a way that it just works as is.

Comment: This is quite crude, but should do the job: write a small Python script that runs silently in the background that frequently reads the clipboard, and, depending on what window is currently focused, writes to the clipboard a suitable representation of the filepath. So when you paste it, it should already be in the right format. Let me know if you want me to write the script, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Also, it's true Explorer doesn't handle \\s in filepaths, but the Run dialog does (Windows key + R). I always use it whenever I need to open a file or directory that I have in my clipboard. It will open Explorer or the application associated for the particular file type.

Comment: @GordonAitchJay I like your creative solution. I think I'll try to write the script myself. It sounds like a nice challenge. Thank you.